# putExtra or getExtras not working

Tags: android-intent

Why in below code Course is not transmitted ?

```
        final List<Course> courses1 = db.findFiltered(String.format("day == %d ", 0),"startTime ASC");
        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.sat);
         registerForContextMenu(lv1);   

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowDetailActivity.class);  
                Log.i("tagID",courses1.get(position).getCourseName());
                //displayed in LogCat
                intent.putExtra(".Course",courses1.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Code in second activity:

```
    course = (Course) getIntent().getExtras().get(".Course");
    //or
    /*Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    course = b.getParcelable(".Course");*/
    Log.i("tagID",course.getCourseName());
    //is not displayed in LogCat
```

Please help Please help Please help

Comment: have u checked the code that i have posted ??

Comment: yes,but when i click on listview items application is crashed!

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: i have update the answer check that

Answer (score 1):

Passing from one activity to other

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

In second activity `oncreate`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

or

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String get_value  = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Change

```
intent.putExtra(".Course",courses1.get(position));
```

by this

```
intent.putExtra(".Course",courses1.get(position).getCourseName())
```

Comment: I test above code carefully and both worked fine but how transmit Course class?

Comment: i didn't get your question please explain more

Comment: courses1.get(position) return Course that in first activity  Log.i("tagID",courses1.get(position).getCourseName());
displayed in LogCat but in second activity                       course = (Course) getIntent().getExtras().get(".Course"); Log.i("tagID",course.getCourseName()); is not displayed in LogCat,i want to transfer the Course class,                                  not string->courses1.get(position).getCourseName() ,thanks for answers

Comment: you want to send a class from one activity to other activity ???I am not able to under stand your problem

Comment: if u got the solution please accept my ans and upvote it